# Xamarin Forms || Adding toolbar with icon is replacing Back bar button in Navigation Bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an iPap add in Xamarin forms.

I am using Navigation.PushAsync and Navigation.PopAsync for navigation. Not using Modals.

SO by default I am getting back button in the navigation bar at the top left . On the right hand side of the naviation bar, I am adding 2 items. When they are text, then it is showing correctly bur when I am replacing Text with Icon then those Icons are coming to left hand side and replacing the back button.

Below code replaces the back button as shown in the figure

```
vat t =new ToolbarItem("Settings", "settings.png", async() => { await Navigation.PushAsync(new TestSetting()); }, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary, 1);       
this.ToolbarItems.Add(t);
```

[image]

Below code replaces the back button as shown in the figure

```
vat t =new ToolbarItem("Settings", null, async() => { await Navigation.PushAsync(new TestSetting()); }, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary, 1);       
this.ToolbarItems.Add(t);
```

[image]

I want to align the tool bar items only to the right hand side with icon. I don't know why adding icon is shifting the tool bar item to left hand side.

Tried setting Order nad Priority but none of the way worked for the Icon.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Not yet. I do not want to use TitleView as I am using C# only (not XAML) as it is very old code. For now, I am going with Text only. If you can help to display the image, then it will be great for me. Also, it is possible to show an Icon just right to the back button without using TitleView? I am focusing only for iPad, not for iPhones.

Comment: Hi, I update my answer using C# only. I also recommend to use TitleView as it can handle more complex scenario. You could have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: to use TitleView in C#**

I recommend to use TitleView as it could handle more complex scenario's with the NavigationBar.

We could use TitleView in pure C#. You could try the following code.

In my code, I define a StackLayout with a Label and ImageButton in it (You could add any other children control you want in this way). And We set the TitleView of the page to this StackLayout.

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{   
    public MyPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        CreateTitleView();
    }

    private void CreateTitleView()
    {
        Label mylabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "mytext",
            TextColor = Color.Blue,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        ImageButton imgbutton = new ImageButton
        {
            Source = "Icon76.png",
        };
        imgbutton.Clicked += Imgbutton_Clicked;

        StackLayout mystack = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Children =
            {
                mylabel,
                imgbutton
            }
        };
        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, mystack);
    }

    private void Imgbutton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

====================

You could use **NavigationPage.TitleView**.You could try the following code.

In TitleView, I use a stacklayout to arrange my control, a button and an image. You could define clicked event or GestureRecognizer for control.

```
<ContentPage
...
    x:Class="AddingToolbarIcon.MyPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <ImageButton Source="monkeyface.png" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked_1"/>
            <Image Source="monkeyface.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
               </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout> 
     </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

By set the Horizontal option the image will place at the right of the navigation bar.

For more info, you could refer to [Displaying Views in the Navigation Bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar).

Hope it works for you.